Understanding assumption in Delta hedging P&L from Bergomi Chapter 1
In Chapter 1 of Bergomi's Stochastic Volatility modelling book there is a derivation of the delta hedging P&L to get a black-scholes like formula.
The derivation in the multi asset case goes something like this.
Suppose there are $n$ assets $S_1,\ldots, S_n$ and there is a pricing function for an option $P(t,S_1,\ldots, S_n)$. Then the (daily) P&L of a delta hedge for a short position in this option has the form
$$P\&L = -(P(t+dt) - P(t)) + r\left(P - \sum_{i=1}^{n}\Delta_i S_i\right) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Delta_i \delta S_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n} q_iS_idt$$ Using the Taylor expansion for $P$ and setting $\Delta_i = \frac{\partial P}{\partial S_i}$ to remove the degree $1$ $dS$ term, we get $$P\&L = -\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}(r-q_i) S_i \frac{\partial P}{\partial S_i} - rP\right)dt - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial S_i \partial S_j}S_iS_j\frac{dS_idS_j}{S_iS_j} = -Adt -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\phi_{i,j}\frac{dS_idS_j}{S_iS_j}$$
The derivation continues a bit in this manner with diagonalizing $\phi$ and writing it in a nice form, but my question is related to a condtion Bergomi imposes: $A = -\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(\phi C)$ where $C$ is a positive definite matrix. He later goes on to say "the condition that our model
is usable – no situation in which our carry P&L is systematically positive or negative – is that there exists a positive break-even covariance matrix $C(t, S)$" such that the above equation holds.
I would like a justification or a motivation for why we should want a condition like this, that $$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}(r-q_i) S_i \frac{\partial P}{\partial S_i} - rP = -\sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial S_i \partial S_j} C_{i,j}$$

Same as the scalar version, your PnL is a statistical quantity and you want its average to be 0, that is the only place where demand and supply will match

I don't follow this case. I am not able to see why this condition is related to the more intuitive condition "average P&L should be 0". Taking expectations on both sides of the second equation above wouldn't work directly

No expectations needed, the delta hedged portfolio has deterministic PnL today until it is rebalanced.

The only statistics that manifest ehre are $dS(i)dS(j)=cov(i,j)*dt$, which is applicable in the differential form. That makes PnL known if you know covariance.

Basically, you require that there exist a dynamics - whatever it is - such that average P&L vanishes.
Given any model for the $S_i$, the resulting realized covariance matrix $C^r_{ij} = \frac{1}{dt}E\left[\frac{dS_idS_j}{S_iS_j}\right]$ is positive.
If no positive $C$ exists such that your last equation holds, then there exists no instance of a realized dynamics for the $S_i$ such that the P&L averages out to zero.
If instead such a $C$ exists, then your average P&L during $dt$ reads:
$$E[P\&L] = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij} \phi_{ij}(C_{ij} - C^r_{ij})dt $$
If realized covariances $C^r_{ij}$ happen to match implied ones $C_{ij}$, the P&L averages out to zero.
